# Using default function parameters on native

Tags: haxe

A haxe function has some parameters whose default values I'd like to use, so I don't need to import anything (they're basic types underneath).  If they were last in the parameter order, I could get away with just not including them.  But they're first, before some defaults I *do* want to override.

I'm not allowed to null them on native.  `_` doesn't compile (I don't think it's meant for this context.)  Am I forced to import and copy the defaults in verbatim, or is there another way?

I tried `.bind(_, ...)()` but that gives `Usage of _ is not supported for optional non-nullable arguments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error comes from the argument having a non-[nullable](http://haxe.org/manual/types-nullability.html) type (`Int`, `Float` or `Bool` on a static target). If this function is part of your code and not some library, you could just make it nullable with `Null<T>` or `?`.

As long as the arguments are nullable, Haxe also allows you to simply *skip* them if they are distuingishable (i.e. the type of the value passed must be different from the one(s) you want to skip). This means you don't have to use `bind()` or explicitly pass `null`. See the fourth example on the manual's [Optional Arguments](http://haxe.org/manual/types-function-optional-arguments.html) page.

If making the arguments nullable isn't an option for you in this particular case, you're probably going to have to copy the defaults (although I'm sure it's possible to come up with a clever macro solution for this).

Comment: I forgot you can just plain skip over them.  Thanks!  (They're part of a library.)

Comment: Except...this technique makes the compiler give the same `Cannot skip non-nullable argument` on Flash, even though it worked on CPP.